# How to write a program that returns a count of strings longer than 10 characters in a list of strings

Tags: python

**Write a program that returns a count of strings longer than 10 characters in a list of strings.**

My program:

```
def count(List):
    if len(List) > 10:
        x = "".count(List)

    if len(List) <= 10:
        x = "None"

    return x

def main():
    Listy = input("Please enter a list of strings: ")
    s = []
    for i in Listy:
        Split = i.replace("[","").replace('"','').replace("]","").split(",")
        s += Split

    y = count(s)
    print(y)

main()
```

**I wrote this program, but seems like there is a problem with the `count()` function. I am not sure why.**

Comment: `List` is a single string; when  you iterate over it, you get each single character in turn; thus `s` is a list of single-character strings. You need to `split` your input on commas, whitespace or some other delineator (which you would need to communicate to the user) to get words.

Comment: ok, let me try that!

Comment: @grayshirt I did what you have told me to do. Getting an error: `Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly`

Comment: Look at the [`split` method](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-split) that strings have:

Comment: input will be like: `["lol","lllllllllllllllllllllllllllll"]`

Comment: Do you want the user to enter a list of words divided by comma or you want the user to enter a single word at the time and each time he enters a word, that word should be added to the list?

Comment: input will be like: ["lol","lllllllllllllllllllllllllllll"]   @JoeR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you how many words in the list have more than 10 characters:

*Note: I used `raw_input` because I use Python 2.7 use `input` in Python 3 also the user will have to enter the words divided by comma and white space*

```
strings = raw_input("Please enter words divided by comma and white space: ")
x = strings.split()
y = []
for i in x:
    if len(i) > 10:
        y.append(i) 
print len(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```
def check_long(lst):
    return len([item for item in lst if len(item) > 10])
```

This creates a filtered list with only the items that have longer than 10 characters, then returns the length of the aforementioned list.

Comment: can you do it in my way? @A.J.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code, This will return list of counts for given lists of strings.

```
def count(strings):
    if len(strings) > 10:
        x = len(strings)

    if len(strings) <= 10:
        x = "None"

    return x

def main():
    List = input("Please enter a list of strings: ")
    y = []
    for i in List:
        y.append(count(i))

    print(y)

main()
```

Output : [16, 20, 'None', 15]

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you

**UPDATED**

```
def count(List):
  if len(List) > 10:
      x = len(List)
  else:
      x = "None"
  return x

def main():
  Listy = input("Please enter a list of strings: ").split(",")
  for index in Listy:
      y = count(index)
      print(y)
```

main()

if input is:

```
lol, llllllllllllllllllll, rfssfsfsdf
```

The output should be:

```
None
21
11
```

Comment: It is just printing out `None`, and not `29`. By the way, I am using Python 3.

Comment: Now I updated the code, tell me if it works for you.